# Which value is larger, $f(1/2)$ vs $f(1/\pi)$, given $f(x)=x^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

I have $f(x)=x^{x}$ and the question,

Which value is larger, $f(1/2)$ or $f(1/\pi)$?

It is easy to find the answer numerically. But, I am keen on an analytical one, with only elementary argument.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because it is too broad.  There are many posts on this site about that function. Since you have thought about it for a long time you should have answers, or at least attempts, at each of your questions. If you are stuck, ask them one at a time.

Comment: It's easier to think of it as $e^{x\log x}$, so for example at zero it extends continuously by taking $1$ as its value, it is decreasing from $0$ to $e^{-1}$ and increasing from there, the range is $[\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{e}}}, \infty)$ etc

Comment: Try graphing it. It's more helpful than you think.

Comment: Looking at its graph will be helpful e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\ln f(x)= x \ln x$. Then $g$ is strictly antitone on $(0,1/e)$, so
$$g(\tfrac{1}{4})>g(\tfrac{1}{\pi})\text{.}$$
But
$$g(\tfrac{1}{4})=g(\tfrac{1}{2})\text{,}$$
so we are done.

Comment: ...... nice .......